# TemplateDoesNotExist, poll/poll.html

Tags: django

I am getting the error TemplateDoesNotExist:

seetings.py

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (SITE_ROOT+'\\templates',)
```

view.py

```
return render(request,'poll/poll.html',{'questions':questions})
```

and my poll.html is inside template/poll/poll.html
my project name is poll_us

print SITE_ROOT
gives /media/gaurav/267CFA707CFA39DF/poll_us
still i am getting the same error. poll.html is not getting found.
please help me out.

Comment: Try to print TEMPLATE_DIRS and see if it helps

Comment: Why are you concatenating path like this? `SITE_ROOT+'\\templates'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it templates or template. You said your TEMPLATE_DIRS is pointing to SITE_ROOT+templates, but your poll templates are in "template" folder.

Comment: sorry it templates not template,,,, spelling mistake,,,,its templates/poll/poll.html

Comment: Could you please try 
SITE_ROOT =os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(`__file__`)))